# How to define a Haskell type that is one of many values

Tags: haskell

I have 3 `data`'s defined:

```
data ActionCard = ActionCard {
  actionCardCost :: Int,
  plusActions :: Int,
  plusBuys :: Int,
  plusCards :: Int,
  plusCoins :: Int
} deriving (Show)

data TreasureCard = TreasureCard {
  treasureCardCost :: Int,
  treasureCardValue :: Int
} deriving (Show)

data VictoryCard = VictoryCard {
  victoryCardCost :: Int,
  victoryCardValue :: Int
} deriving (Show)
```

I want to define `Card` such that anywhere a `Card` type is used, it means the value is either an instance of `ActionCard`, `TreasureCard`, or `VictoryCard`.

Basically I want `Card` to be an interface that the three all implement, to borrow from OOP.

I want to be able to write

```
type Deck = [Card]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with sum types?  `data Card = VC VictoryCard | TC TreasureCard | ...`?  Would that work for you?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but judging from your code I can't help but assume you're coding some sort of Dominion game or application - as a huge fan of the game (as well as budding Haskell programmer) I'd love to see what you eventually come up with :)